# What's the best type-checking for 'onChange' union type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a component which dynamically can be input or date-picker.

Let's say component is provided props as...

```
interface Props {
  //...
  onChange:
    | ((
        date: Date,
        event: React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event> | undefined
      ) => void)
    | ((e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void);
}

const DynamicField = (props: Props) => {

    //...
    if (props.type === 'date-picker') {
       return (
            <DatePicker
                onChange={props.onChange}
                //other props...

    }
```

TypeScript claims an error because DatePicker only accepts of type as

```
((date: Date, event: React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event> | undefined) => void)
```

Is it possible to check correct function type at the if statement?

I ended up using type assertion but I'm insecure about it.

```
<DatePicker
   onChange={props.onChange as ((date: Date, event: React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event> | undefined) => void)}
)}
```

EDIT : [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/onchange-type-checking-e5p0k?file=/src/DynamicField.tsx)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlpRxN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your reply. I added code sandbox. There's no errors in editor but I'm not sure it is right to just type asserting the function not conditionally checking the types.

Comment: When I go there I see an immediate error on `import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";` so that's probably not what you're trying to demonstrate.  Also, you might want to show how leaving off `as DateHandler` leads to errors, so someone could investigate fixing it without a type assertion.  But since `react-datepicker` is not found, I'm not seeing anything useful in the IDE.

Comment: It sounds like `Props` should be turned into a discriminated union on the `type` property to get proper type narrowing. But as @jcalz said, without something to reproduce we're guessing here.